# ng-options not updating when model changed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I have a JSON object that looks like:

```
[
   {
    "empName": "John",
    "ID": 1
   },
   {
    "empName": "Sam",
    "ID": 2
   },
   {
    "empName": "Ben",
    "ID": 3
   }
]
```

In the view I want a dropdown where the user selects one of the names.  I'm using `ng-options` to achieve this:

```
<select ng-options="item as item.empName for item in employees track by item.ID" ng-model="emp.selected">
</select>
```

If I hard-code the JSON into the variable `employees` in my controller the select renders. However if I use:

```
$.getJSON("path to JSON file",function(json){
    $scope.employees = json;
});
```

The select is not populated.  I've tried adding in $scope.$apply() to no avail.  Any suggestions?

**Update 1**

Taking on board the answer from Iso I'm still left with the select not binding.  For example If my javascript is:

```
app.controller('Ctrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {

    $scope.employees = [
       {
        "empName": "John",
        "ID": 1
       },
    ];

    $http.get(" --PATH TO JSON-- ").then(function (res) {
        $scope.employees = res.data;
        console.log($scope.employees);
    });
}]);
```

The select is still only populated with the first name 'John' despite the fact that the `console.log` returns the full object with all three names.

Answer (score 1):

You need to either call `$scope.$evalAsync()`, or use `$http` instead of jQuery here (which I would recommend):

```
$http.get("path to JSON file").then(function (res) {
  $scope.employees = res.data;
});
```

The reason for this is that `$http` is aware of AngularJS' digest cycle, whereas jQuery is not.

Refrain from using `$scope.$apply()` (which can fail if a digest cycle is in progress), and `$timeout` (which is heavy since it provokes a digest cycle of all your scopes).

Comment: Hi Iso I'm afraid that didn't seem to work.  If you'd be able to take a look at Update 1 it'd be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your code inside `$timeout`:

```
$.getJSON("path to JSON file", function (json) {
    $timeout(function () {
        $scope.employees = json;
    })
});
```

The call to `$apply` may fail when the digest cycle is already in progress.

But consider using the `$http` instead of using jQuery to pull data.

Comment: Hi Shashank this is returning an error 'Cannot read property 'protocol' of undefined'.  I can't seem to diagnose it.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You should use promises with the `$q` library in Angular.

```
var getEmployees = function () {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        $.getJSON("path to JSON file", function (json) {
            deferred.resolve(json);
        });
        return deferred.promise;
    }

    getEmployees().then(res){
        $scope.employees = res.data;
    }
```

**EDIT**
If you use `$timeout` is not really as correct a solution, as it doesn't give you control over the synchronicity. However, using `$http` to make your calls comes with promises built in, I believe.

Comment: Hi itamar I'm afraid I have tried this and it doesn't seem to be working.  Even in the response if I hard-code additional employees the view is not showing the names in the select.